# sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed socket <zmq.Socket(zmq.PUSH) at 0x7f8a5c016d60>

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pyzmq

I am running spyder in WSL on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with XLaunch. When I run my code (no blank file, or anything), I get the following message in the console:
`runfile('/home/picky/Research/trans_CGM_Multiprobes.py', wdir='/home/picky/Research') 02-Mar-22 22:18:21: sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed socket <zmq.Socket(zmq.PUSH) at 0x7f8a492549a0>`

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

I running Python Version 3.9.7 [GCC 7.5.0],
Spyder 5.1.5,
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on WSL,
Qt 5.9.7,
PyQT5 5.9.2

Code (irrelevant, since everytime I f5 to run file, this happens):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Author: Patrick
March 3rd 2022
"""

import numpy as np
```

which returns

```
In[32]:
"""
Author: Patrick
March 3rd 2022
"""

import numpy as np
02-Mar-22 22:35:41: sys:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed socket <zmq.Socket(zmq.PUSH) at 0x7f8a49238f40>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] -- the shortest possible code someone else can run without changes to cause that same error.

Comment: (in general, this means what it says -- that you're creating a zeroMQ socket but not explicitly closing it -- but we'd need to see code that unexpectedly causes the error to speak to _why_ it's unexpected, assuming that your code _tries_ to close the socket but somehow isn't doing so; right now, without any code shared, we don't know if you're even making an attempt to close the socket or not, so any answers are necessarily very speculative).

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy, I've added a minimal reproduciable exmaple. However, I didn't include it initally, since this message appears on ANY instances when I run ANYTHING. I am stumped, perhaps it has something to do with my python settings?

Comment: That's illuminating, insofar as it tells us it's not your code importing pyzmq and thus that it's necessary to look closely at other projects in use. It happens only with the numpy import?

Comment: What a wonderful hint! I had previously ran another package which (I guess) had somethign to do with pyzmq. I restarted my console and the error was gone - the old off and on again trick worked. Thanks for helping gain a better understanding what what zeroMQ meant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q :**
> *<sub>" What does this mean, and how can I fix it? "</sub>*

**A :**
The **MEANING** : Spyder is to be blamed (except where WSL fail to emulate `ipc:` over W10 pipe)
and **REMEDY** : check for more recent updates, if available & notify Spyder developers to do a better self-healing code-design, that uses ZeroMQ best-practices to unlock and release all resources they setup internally in due tiame and fashion ( no offense, just be also informed that some recent ZeroMQ native API default might cause another level of code-refactoring, as assumed-only behaviours have started to fail (self)-execute after a new, other default value starts to turn such use of implicit-only-logic upside down - `zmq.LINGER` being one such potential cause for indefinite hanging `zmq.PUSH`-socket, instead of being `.close()`-ed, right due to such `zmq.LINGER`-related behaviour.

Spyder & similar IDE tools started to heavily use ZeroMQ internally many years ago, which -for obvious reasons- started to cause problems (not only when users instantiated own ZeroMQ Context()-s) colliding in using localhost resources. As internal Spyder crashes keep appearin (some salvageable with console/IDE soft-reset(s), some not) some Spyder's usage of ZeroMQ resources was not in all cases programmed in a robust-enough, self-healing manner -- some of internal crashes did indeed leave some of the ZeroMQ resources hung (as you've seen above). Reboot sometimes being the only way one had to resort to, so as to finally release'em